# I'm trying to remove Wine and everything back to normal. never used it and have no need for it

Tags: wine

I made a mistake and no I want to get rid of this

```
Get:8 [https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu](https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu) bionic InRelease \[6,259 B\]

Err:8 [https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu](https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu) bionic InRelease

  The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO\_PUBKEY 76F1A20FF987672F

Reading package lists... Done

W: GPG error: [https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu](https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu) bionic InRelease: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO\_PUBKEY 76F1A20FF987672F

E: The repository '[https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu](https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu) bionic InRelease' is not signed.

N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.

N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

Comment: Please let us know if the linked answer(s) don't work (although, this is the answer you are looking for).

Comment: There are ways to get rid of the public key error as well but removing the repository will also take care of the issue.

Comment: Yes, this worked for me